# Qlik Sense Extension (sense-export)

Tags: qliksense

Has anyone used this extension (https://github.com/stefanwalther/sense-export)? It is an export button from GitHub.

It's pretty good, but I have not been able to have a specific filename. The default name is a unique identifier and I need to generate the excel file with a specific name to use it within another tool automatically.

Comment: it sounds like you are using sense as a bit of an etl tool - not sure if you're going about this the right way - depending on your second import, could you not pick up any new files in a set location?

Comment: Actually not as ETL tool but there are two columns need to be update in the database according to certain selection in Qlik Sense. as you know there is no possibility to write data to back to the database, therefore I make selections and then export the selected data to an excel file. Then, I developed an C# Form to read the data from the excel file and and run the update query. I know it is a little bit strange but I asked to do this task.

What I want I need to export the data to excel file with specific name to be able to read it from C# Form easily.

Comment: I would say that this probably isn't the right tool for the job and I wouldn't trust anyone to automatically update a database without the right knowledge about what they're doing. It would be easier if when they wanted to export the data, the user then sent it to someone sensible that could then take on the job of updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

A better place to ask these questions is on the github repository itself, Stefan who created the extension is very active in the Qlik community and I'm sure would be able to provide more detail - unfortunately the extensions by nature are not mainstream and you will not be able to get as much support for them as standard products.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have asked there too. I think currently Stefan is busy or so, because I have not received any reply from him.

Comment: ;-) Haven't seen a question/issue on GitHub, please file it there, I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an extension, you can change / customize the JavaScript to do whatever you want.  In your case, in swr-sense-export.js, lines 48 through 53 are:

```
var exportOpts = {
    format: $scope.layout.props.exportFormat,
    state: $scope.layout.props.exportState,
    filename: $scope.layout.props.exportFileName,
    download: true
};
```

So you could change the filename to whatever you want.